# CSS/Javascript static resources not loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, static-resources

I've loaded css/js static resources to Salesforce in a fivestar.zip file. This resource also contains an svg.

fivestar.zip
--rating.css
--rating.js
--stars.svg
When attempting to load these resources via

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.fivestar + '/rating.css'}" 
              scripts="{!$Resource.fivestar + '/rating.js'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

I'm getting the following 404 errors via Chrome console :

GET https://curious-badger-85919-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1534019843000/fivestar/rating.js 404 (Not Found)
 
and

GET https://curious-badger-85919-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1534019843000/fivestar/rating.css 404 (Not Found)
I'm assuming this has to do with my **ltng:require** tag being incorrect, which is why I haven't included other code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your tag seems correct, its your file path that seems to be off, mind sharing your zip file tree structure?

Did you zip the files directly, or you zipped a filder that contains these 3 files? if the later is your case, then your reference should be something similar to the below:

```
<ltng:require 
    styles="{!$Resource.fivestart+ 'toplevelfolder/rating.css'}"
    scripts="{!$Resource.fivestart+ 'toplevelfolder/fivestar.js'}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

Comment: @gils I zipped a folder containing these files. That worked - thank you.

Comment: I've also found that quitting and reopening chrome sometimes solves this issue, especially when hosting components in communities. Seems like there's caching going on that causes sporadic issues loading static resources.

Comment: might be that you have persistent browser caching  enabled in your org - you can disable it under session settings